# Sending Response Header with the Serverless Framework on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using the Serverless Framework for my Lambda functions on AWS. How can I send authorization headers? My current config:

**Lambda function**:

```
module.exports.createUser = (event, context, callback) => {

     let response = {
            statusCode: 302,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": userUtil.getToken(userId)
            },
            body: ""
        };
    callback(null, response);
    return;
}
```

**serverless.yml**:

```
createUser:
    handler: functions/user.createUser
    events:
      - http:
          path: users
          method: post
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
```

The above config sends the response object as body. The status is still 200.

I'm using Serverless v1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the status code, headers and body in your code, instead of adding them in your configuration, you need to use the Lambda-proxy setting. See more [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway).

Lambda-proxy is the default type. So you need to remove the `integration: lambda` in your **serverless.yml**. Also, remove the `cors: true` setting and modify the **handler.js** to add CORS headers.

Modify your **Lambda function** to:

```
module.exports.createUser = (event, context, callback) => {

    let response = {
        statusCode: 302,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": userUtil.getToken(userId),
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
        },
        body: ""
    };

    callback(null, response);
    return;
}
```

Modify your **serverless.yml** file to:

```
createUser:
    handler: functions/user.createUser
    events:
      - http:
          path: users
          method: post
```

Comment: Thanks @Zanon. Rookie mistake! I should have read on Lambda-proxy.